# How can I add a suffix to all file names with a certain extension and keep the extension at the end of the name?

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I've been trying to add the suffix `_new` to all `.c` files in a certain directory.  For example, I want the file named `example.c` to be called `example_new.c`.

I tried to use a for loop:

`for i in *.c; do mv "$i" "$i"_new; done`

But this makes `example.c` become `example.c_new` and I don't know how to make it correct. I was thinking about using `sed`, but I'm not sure if it can help.

Answer (score 4):

A small tweak to Rinzwind's answer: in order to match the requested pattern, the `mv` command should be:

```
mv "$file" "${file%.c}_new.c"
```

Note that the form they use will silently overwrite files if the name already exists; use the `-i` flag in order to be prompted for collisions during interactive use.

Note also that in general I recommend doing a dry run first, by adding `echo` before the `mv` command:

```
echo mv "$file" "${file%.c}_new.c"
```

The files can also be renamed using "mmv" (with a dry run first):

```
mmv -n '*.c' '#1_new.c'
mmv -v '*.c' '#1_new.c'
```

By default, mmv will ask the user before overwriting files.

Comment: Thank you Klode ... I have applied some of your notes to @Rinzwind's answer and thought it would be fair to leave this notice here ... +1

Answer (score 3):

With the [rename](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rename.ul.1.html) command (`sudo apt install rename`)

```
rename -n 's/\.c/_new.c/ if -f' -- *.c
```

- When satisfied with the output, change `-n` (dry-run mode) with `-v` to show a verbose version of the output.
- `if -f` should exclude directories and rename only files.

In bash you can also do:

```
for file in *.c
do
     [ ! -d "${file%.c}_new.c" ] && [ -f "$file" ] && echo mv -nv -- "$file" "${file%.c}_new.c"
done
```

- When satisfied with the output, remove `echo` (dry-run mode) to do the actual renaming.
- `[ ! -d "${file%.c}_new.c" ]` should prevent moving into directories if the new name happened to exist as a directory.
- `[ -f "$file" ]` should exclude directories hence renaming only files.

Answer (score 1):

## Using find and mv:

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.c}_new.c"' sh {} \;
```

This command uses find to locate all .c files and then executes a sh command to rename each file by removing the .c extension and adding _new.c.

## Using a for loop:

```bash
for file in *.c; do
    mv "$file" "${file%.c}_new.c"
done
```

This for loop iterates through all .c files in the directory, and for each file, it renames it by removing the .c extension and appending _new.c.

Choose the method that best suits your system and preferences. Always exercise caution when bulk-renaming files and consider testing in a safe environment or creating backups.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `find` will search and pass matching filenames from all sub-directories (not just the search directory's first level) unless `-maxdepth 1` is specified ... and `mv` in your loop will attempt to rename directories as well.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has a regular expression matching operator `=~` that when used with RegEx capture groups in parenthesis `(...)` inside extended test brackets `[[ ... ]]` gets the portions matching each capture group stored in a special array [`BASH_REMATCH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH) as array elements starting from index `1` for the portion matching the first capturing group, `2` for the second and so on ... So you could use Regular expressions matching like this:

```bash
for f in *.c
  do 
    if [[ "$f" =~ ^(.*)(\.c)$ ]] 
      then
      [ ! -d "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_new${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ] && \
      [ -f "$f" ] && \
      echo mv -nv -- "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_new${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
      fi
    done
```

**Notice** that `echo` is added for a safe dry-run ... When satisfied with the output, remove it for the actual renaming to happen.

Demonstration:

```
$ touch file{1..3}.c
$ 
$ for f in *.c
  do 
    if [[ "$f" =~ ^(.*)(\.c)$ ]] 
      then
      [ ! -d "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_new${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ] && \
      [ -f "$f" ] && \
      mv -nv -- "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_new${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
      fi
    done
renamed 'file1.c' -> 'file1_new.c'
renamed 'file2.c' -> 'file2_new.c'
renamed 'file3.c' -> 'file3_new.c'
$
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Nov 25 14:25 file1_new.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Nov 25 14:25 file2_new.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Nov 25 14:25 file3_new.c
```